# How do I switch between factor level?

Tags: r

First off, there are 2 categorical variables in my logistic regression.

My response is Vector of "yes" and "no"

My 1st explanatory is Vector of "black" and "white"

My 2nd explanatory is Vector of "yes" and "no"

For one of my explanatory, let's say the default for being "black" is 0 and "white" is 1

Another explanatory variable has default value of "Yes" as 1 and "No" as 0.

Now if I wanted to make the default for being "white" as 0 and "black" to be 1

and for another explanatory, make the default for "yes" to be 0 and "no" to be 1.

How would I do this?

It sounds easy but complicated to code.

Comment: I would use TRUE/FALSE instead of Yes/No.  It makes things easier to code, since the values 1 and 0 are already assigned to TRUE and FALSE, respectively.

Comment: It doesn't matter which one is which. If you are wanting to change the reference groups, you could just use `relevel` within the model formula instead of recoding your data.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are hoping for, but my guess is that you are trying to get the base or reference levels for the `glm` function in R to be reporting the coefficient for the treatment effect of the "first explanatory vector to be "white" and for "second explanatory vector" to be "yes". (Neither of those would be the default situation since the default is alpha sort order for factors.)

```
 dat$first <- factor(dat$first, levels=c("white","black") 
 dat$second <- factor(dat$second, levels=c("yes", "no") )
 glm( I(response=="yes") ~ first + second, data=dat, family="binomial")
```